# Mapeo de JSON a array de objetos en typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, net

Estoy intentando pasar una lista de usuarios creada en net core 6 y mapearla en una interfaz en Angular.
Creando un array de usuarios a mostrar en un autocomplete.

```
JsonResult res = new JsonResult();
 List<Category> Users = con.users.OrderBy(c => c.Por).ToList();
 res.Data = Users
 return res;
```

El problema es que no se exactamente como volcarlo en un Array de users en ANGULAR.He intentado usar:

```
Json.parse(data)
```

Algún ejemplo que pueda usar?

Comment: Has intentado usar `Json.parse` pero realmente se escribe `JSON.parse`. Por otro lado, has depurado lo que recibes? Has analizado las cabeceras de respuesta? Faltan muchos detalles en tu pregunta. Si has intentado usar aquello que pones en la pregunta, ¿te marca error? ¿Cuál es el mensaje de ese error? Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Unicamente necesito saber como enviar una lista de objetos tipo usuario en este caso.No hay ningun error simplemente no se mapea me imagino por que la estructura del objeto no es la correcta